# tokenize function koRpus package

Tags: r

I want to know if tokenize function in koRpus package can run on text which contain only a single word (no space , no fullstop). I have got the following error:

Error in `[.data.frame`(tagged.text, , "token") : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Post your code in full, [dput](http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-an-r-object-to-text-with-dput/)() any data, and put any images on [imgur](http:///www.imgur.com), please?

Comment: txt<-c("english french","english","french") ; library(tm); library(SnowballC); library(koRpus);                                                     for(i in 1:3){v<-txt[i]; token1<-tokenize(v, format = "obj", fileEncoding ="UTF-8", split = "[[:space:]]",ign.comp = "-", heuristics = "abbr,suf,pre", heur.fix = list(pre = c("’","'"), suf = c("’", "'")), abbrev = NULL, tag = TRUE, lang = "en",sentc.end = c(".", "!", "?", ";", ":"), detect = c(parag = FALSE, hline = FALSE), clean.raw = NULL, perl = FALSE, stopwords = tm::stopwords("en"),stemmer = SnowballC::wordStem)}

Comment: the above code gives the error of Error in `[.data.frame`(tagged.text, , "token") : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: If I use only the first text i.e. "english french" and change the value of i from 1:3 to 1 only, then the code is running fine.. So the question is if tokenize function can take text which contain only a single word or not? And if not, is there any way out? My end objective is to use the tokenize output as an input in readability function.

Comment: How about using only the first text and keeping the loop the same? Does that work?

Comment: This was just an example to demonstrate if the error is because of space or any other issue. Eventually I want to use all the three texts..